# Automapper Round All Decimal Type Instances

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-6

I need a way to add rounding to my automapper configuration. I have tried using the IValueFormatter as suggested here: [Automapper Set Decimals to all be 2 decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111432/automapper-set-decimals-to-all-be-2-decimals)

But AutoMapper no longer supports formatters. I don't need to covert it to a different type, so I'm not sure a type converter is the best solution either.

Is there still a good automapper solution for this problem now?

Using AutoMapper version 6.11

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137734/whats-the-alternative-to-ivalueformatter-in-automapper

Comment: The problem with that solution is that means I have to go through and find every decimal type instance. I want to do this by decimal type, not by property.

Comment: Just create a map from decimal to decimal and apply that formatter.  You don't need to do it everywhere.  Just tell automapper how to map decimals to decimals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a complete MCVE demonstrating how you can configure the mapping of `decimal` to `decimal`.  In this example I round all decimal values to two digits:

```
public class FooProfile : Profile
{
    public FooProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<decimal, decimal>().ConvertUsing(x=> Math.Round(x,2));
        CreateMap<Foo, Foo>();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public decimal X { get; set; }
}
```

Here, we demonstrate it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x=> x.AddProfile(new FooProfile()));

        var foo = new Foo() { X = 1234.4567M };
        var foo2 = Mapper.Map<Foo>(foo);
        Debug.WriteLine(foo2.X);
    }
}
```

Expected output:

> 1234.46

While its true that Automapper knows how to map a `decimal` to a `decimal` out of the box, we can override its default configuration and tell it how to map them to suit our needs.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided above is correct. Just wanted to point out that we can also achieve this using AutoMapper's `MapperConfiguration` as well, instead of `Profiles`.

We can modify the above code to use `MapperConfiguration` as follows.

Define the Foo class

```
public class Foo
{
        public decimal X { get; set; }
}
```

Modify the main method as follows:

```
class Program
{
    private IMapper _mapper;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitialiseMapper();

        var foo = new Foo() { X = 1234.4567M };
        var foo2 = _mapper.Map<Foo>(foo);
        Debug.WriteLine(foo2.X);
    }

    private void InitialiseMapper()
    {
        var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                CreateMap<decimal, decimal>().ConvertUsing(x=> Math.Round(x,2));
                CreateMap<Foo, Foo>();                   
            });

            _mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();            
    }
}
```